# How would I create a new NSWindow via Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, instance, nswindow

I would just like to know how to create ("instance") a new NSWindow in a Mac OSX application via it's Objective-C code.

Comment: Note that there is typical *very little* reason to programmatically create windows.  Generally, you simply use Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the "Creating Windows" section of the [NSWindow class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - it tells you pretty much all you need to know about creating windows programmatically.

Additionally, there's quite a bit of sample code (see the "Related sample code" section at the top of the above link) if you're after examples.